Under what conditions are the remaining coefficients of a regression with a variable omitted "scaled" relative to those in the complete regression?
I was reading this article that discusses the impact of ommitting variable from a regression equation, and analyzes the impact it will have.
Here is some notation they use: given a data matrix $X$, response variable $y$, we have the normal equations for the regression coefficients given by:
$$\widehat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'y$$
Now suppose we have ommitted some variable z. If we re-ran the regression with that variable included, we would have new regression coefficients $\beta, \gamma$, such that
$$y \sim X\beta + z\gamma$$
They then give the equation for the coefficients of the regression with the ommitted variable in terms of the coefficients of the complete regression:
$$\widehat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'y=(X'X)^{-1}X'(X\beta + z\gamma + \epsilon)$$
$$=(X'X)^{-1}X'X\beta +(X'X)^{-1}X'z\gamma + (X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon $$
In my particular case, each of the regression variables in X is a random (uncorrelated) bernoulli variable taking values in $\{0,1\}$, so they all have the same mean and variance and no covariance.
I'm trying to use the kind of analysis above to understand the conditions under which the following is true: when we omit a variable, the remaining coefficients all simply get scaled proportionally, so that the predicted value when all of them are set to 1 remains the same as before.
In other words, let's say that we have the following value when all of the regression variables in the complete regression are set to 1 (i.e. the sum of all of the regression variables):
$$C=\widehat{\beta}\mathbf{1}+\gamma$$
Under what conditions is it the case that $$\widehat{\beta} = \frac{\beta}{C-\gamma}?$$
My intuition is that this should be the case in my special case, and I'm trying to prove whether or not its true. the reason I think it should be true is that when you omit the variable, the prediction when all regression variables are set to 1 will be too low, and needs to be scaled up. Since all of the variables have the same variance and no correlation, I would think they should all be scaled up by the same amount proportionally.
Can someone help me prove this statement, or a different one that is similarly simple based on the constraints of my special case that is actually correct?
Unfortunately, from glancing at the above math, it seems that since each of the regressors in $X$ and $z$ are uncorrelated, $X'z=0$, and so there should be no expected "inflation" to the regression coefficients in the incomplete regression. But that doesn't seem correct...
Thank you,
Paul
